# How do I represent this query using built-in Grails/GORM methods

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

So i have this query below and it works, but I want to avoid writing explicitly HQL and use the methods available within Grails/GORM.  How can I achieve this?

I have an Event which contains many RSVP (1 for each person).  This query is finding which events a specific user HAS NOT rsvp for yet.  It LEFT JOINS the Rsvp table with the Event table based on the user_id.  I check to see if the Rsvp is null.

```
def events = Event.executeQuery("""
        SELECT event
        FROM Event AS event
        LEFT JOIN event.rsvps AS rsvp
            WITH rsvp.user.id = ?
        WHERE event.active = 1
        AND event.startDate >= ?
        AND rsvp.id IS NULL
    """, [(long)1, new Date().clearTime()]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an approximation. I doubt the LEFT OUTER JOIN will work, but it should give you the idea:

```
import static org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.*

def events = Event.withCriteria {
    createAlias('rsvps', 'r', LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
    // I'm not sure about the following line. Aliases change things a bit
    // Besides, it conflicts with the isNull().
    eq('r.user.id', 1) 
    eq('active', 1)
    ge('startDate', new Date().clearTime())
    isNull('r.id')
}
```

There's one of my articles you may find helpful: http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/